# edit the order of link appearances in links__system_main_menu

Tags: routes, navigation

I have setup links through the Drupal 7 web interface, however I am trying to change the order of the link appearances through code. For example, currently I have:

```
ABOUT US          CONTACT US          HOME          THE PRODUCT
```

The order is clearly incorrect, but I cannot find a way to edit the PHP code to edit the order of the appearances of these links. I am aware of overriding MYTHEME_menu_link to get this done, however I do not know what code would be required to go in there to actually perform the change.

I am new to PHP so any help would be appreciated.

Also, the following is my code. It works (looks the way I want it), but I  do not think this is the correct way to do it in Drupal, if someone could please correct me I would appreciate it

```
<div id='menu-bar'>
  <div id='inner'>
    <ul id="menu-top" class="menu">
          <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
          'links' => $main_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'main-menu',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Main menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
    )); ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

EDIT: I know you can edit the order of links through the web interface, but as a developer I do not feel quite comfortable just using the web interface for everything, I would like to learn how to do the actual coding.

Comment: It seems really silly to me not to use UI when there is one. As if there was not enough work with the rest already ? If you really can't live with it, the correct attribute is `weight`.

Comment: Code would be the wrong place to do something like this. Even if you were able to permanently override the weight of each menu item via your code, you would effectively break the user interface for re-arranging links. Part of being a good developer is knowing which situations call for using custom code and which situations call for using the existing interfaces.

Comment: I see, so for situations such as this it would be correct to just use the web interface. Thanks.